# Excel PowerQuery Return Value From Next Matching Value

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a set of data as follows, which I am importing into Excel via PowerQuery to draw in multiple files and apply transformations across the dataset:

| TransactionID | TransactionType | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Log On | 01/01/2022 09:00 |
| 2 | Search | 01/01/2022 09:05 |
| 3 | Open | 01/01/2022 09:06 |
| 4 | Update | 01/01/2022 09:07 |
| 5 | Open | 01/01/2022 09:09 |
| 6 | Open | 01/01/2022 09:12 |
| 7 | Update | 01/01/2022 09:14 |
| 8 | Log On | 01/02/2022 09:00 |
| 9 | Search | 01/01/2022 09:03 |
| 10 | Open | 01/01/2022 09:05 |
| 11 | Open | 01/01/2022 09:07 |
| 12 | Update | 01/01/2022 09:08 |

I need to pull this into Excel to generate a dashboard but need to show within this the rough time a user was logged on to the system. Unfortunately the log off is not (always) captured so I need to infer this from the transaction before the next Log On.
As such I would like to add a step to the query that, for each Log On, finds the next Log On and then brings the Date/Time back from the row above. If there is no next Log On I would like to just apply the data from the last row - so the data I would like would look like this:

| TransactionID | TransactionType | DateTime | LastDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Log On | 01/01/2022 09:00 | 01/01/2022 09:14 |
| 2 | Search | 01/01/2022 09:05 |  |
| 3 | Open | 01/01/2022 09:06 |  |
| 4 | Update | 01/01/2022 09:07 |  |
| 5 | Open | 01/01/2022 09:09 |  |
| 6 | Open | 01/01/2022 09:12 |  |
| 7 | Update | 01/01/2022 09:14 |  |
| 8 | Log On | 01/02/2022 09:00 | 01/01/2022 09:08 |
| 9 | Search | 01/01/2022 09:03 |  |
| 10 | Open | 01/01/2022 09:05 |  |
| 11 | Open | 01/01/2022 09:07 |  |
| 12 | Update | 01/01/2022 09:08 |  |

I have managed to use an Index column to draw back data from the same or different rows by an absolute reference but can not work through how to find the row of the next Log On.
Is anyone able to point me in the right way on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best that came to mind at the moment in powerquery. You can try

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"TransactionID", Int64.Type}, {"TransactionType", type text}, {"DateTime", type datetime}}),

// add extra Log On row at bottom in case bottom row is not a Log On row. Will be removed later
#"Kept Last Rows" = Table.LastN(#"Changed Type", 1),
#"extrarow" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Kept Last Rows",{{"TransactionType", each "Log On", type text}}),

#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type" & #"extrarow", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

// copy date times from previous rows
shiftedList = {null} & List.RemoveLastN( #"Added Index"[DateTime],1) ,
custom1 = Table.ToColumns( #"Added Index") & {shiftedList},
custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames( #"Added Index") & {"PreviousDateTime"}),

// Filter Log Ons and copy from row beneath
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(custom2, each ([TransactionType] = "Log On")),
shiftedList2 = List.RemoveFirstN(#"Filtered Rows"[PreviousDateTime],1),
custom3 = Table.ToColumns( #"Filtered Rows") & {shiftedList2},
custom4 = Table.FromColumns(custom3,Table.ColumnNames( #"Filtered Rows") & {"LastDateTime"}),

// recombine Log On and Non Log On, resort, then remove the false row
combined = Table.SelectRows(custom2, each ([TransactionType] <> "Log On")) & custom4,
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(combined,{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index", "PreviousDateTime"}),
#"Removed Bottom Rows" = Table.RemoveLastN(#"Removed Columns",1),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Bottom Rows",{{"LastDateTime", type datetime}})
in #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Note I am using the index column for a sort, not for finding the previous or next row. This way is faster for larger data sets

| TransactionID | TransactionType | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Log On | 01/01/22 09:00 |
| 2 | Search | 01/01/22 09:05 |
| 3 | Open | 01/01/22 09:06 |
| 4 | Update | 01/01/22 09:07 |
| 5 | Open | 01/01/22 09:09 |
| 6 | Open | 01/01/22 09:12 |
| 7 | Update | 01/01/22 09:14 |
| 8 | Log On | 01/02/22 09:00 |
| 9 | Search | 01/01/22 09:03 |
| 10 | Open | 01/01/22 09:05 |
| 11 | Open | 01/01/22 09:07 |
| 12 | Update | 01/01/22 09:08 |
| 13 | Log On | 01/02/22 09:05 |
| 14 | Search | 01/01/22 09:06 |
| 15 | Open | 01/01/22 09:07 |
| 16 | Open | 01/01/22 09:08 |
| 17 | Update | 01/01/22 09:09 |
| 18 | Log On | 01/02/22 09:15 |
| 19 | Search | 01/01/22 09:03 |
| 20 | Open | 01/01/22 09:05 |
| 21 | Open | 01/01/22 09:07 |
| 22 | Update | 01/01/22 09:08 |

Comment: Thanks for the code - I have had one attempt and keep getting an error on the PreviousDateTime which I will attempt to debug in the morning. I was going down the same path of splitting of the data and re-joining it but had not got far down that part.

Comment: how did that work for you